# Azure function connecting to database on a Azure VM

Tags: azure-functions

New to Azure. I have an existing SQL Server database on an Azure VM. I would like to create a REST API using Azure functions which calls a store procedure on the database.

Is this possible to do in the consumption plan? If so, how would I set it up?

Comment: Should be possible, connect to the database just like you would. Got nothing to do with what your plan is (consumption or other).

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "can I connect to my VM via a VNet?", then the answer is no, not in Consumption plan. For [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#virtual-network-integration) you need App Service Plan or Premium Consumption. If you want to connect via a public IP, though, this will work from Consumption plan as well.

Comment: OK thanks, is public IP method secure? or can you restrict access to google functions ip range?

Comment: @Swordfish you can whitelist/restrict ip addresses at the VM NIC level. You could try adding the Google Functions ip range, but these ip addresses might change if they're dynamic.